# JetBrains dotCover code coverage analysis fails with error "Invalid stream header"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, resharper, dotcover

I'm trying to determine the unit test coverage of my .Net Core solution in Visual Studio 2015 using JetBrains dotCover.

Unfortunately, it fails with error "Coverage analysis: Invalid stream header!".

I'm using ReSharper Ultimate version 2016.3.2.

From the logs:

```
|I| UnitTestSessionManager | HandleAnalysisFinished
|I| CoverageSnapshotManager | Merging snapshots 1-4
|I| CoverageSnapshotManager | Merge finished
|I| UnitTestSessionOperationManager| Operation aborted
|I| UnitTestSessionOperationManager| Operation error: Invalid stream header!
|I| UnitTestSessionOperationManager| Operation finished
|W| | Invalid stream header!

--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [PdbException]
Message = “Invalid stream header!”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = JetBrains.Metadata.Utils.Pdb.Common.PdbException
HResult = COR_E_EXCEPTION=80131500
Source = JetBrains.Platform.Metadata
StackTraceString = “
at JetBrains.Metadata.Utils.Pdb.PdbHeader..ctor(BinaryReader reader)
at JetBrains.Metadata.Utils.Pdb.PdbFile..ctor(Stream pdbStream)
at JetBrains.dotCover.DataAccess.SnapshotCore.Dal.Complementer.CoverageSnapshotStorageComplementer.TryGetAssemblyMetadataAndPdb(Lifetime lifetime, FileSystemPath assemblyPath, Stream& metadataStream, PdbFile& pdbFile)
at JetBrains.dotCover.DataAccess.SnapshotCore.Dal.Complementer.CoverageSnapshotStorageComplementer.Complement(ISnapshotStorage sourceStorage, IStorageSectionWriter storageAppender, ISnapshotScopeInfoProvider snapshotScopeInfoProvider, Predicate`1 includeModule, IEnumerable`1 patternFilters, IEnumerable`1 attributeFilters, IProgressIndicator progress)
at JetBrains.dotCover.DataAccess.SnapshotCore.Dal.CoverageSnapshotManager.Complement(IStorageDescriptor source, ISnapshotScopeInfoProvider snapshotScopeInfoProvider, Predicate`1 includeModule, IEnumerable`1 patternFilters, IEnumerable`1 attributeFilters, IProgressIndicator progress)
at JetBrains.dotCover.Workspace.Impl.UnitTesting.Model.UnitTestSessionManager.HandleAnalysisFinished(ProgressId progressId, Boolean complementSnapshot, CoverageFilterSet coverageFilters, AttributeFilterSet attributeFilters, ElementInfoProvider elementInfoProvider)
at SyncInvokeHandleAnalysisFinished(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
”

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = “Invalid stream header!”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException”
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.HandleErrorCommon(Exception error, ErrorHandlerFaultInfo& faultInfo)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessageCleanup(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.ProcessError(Exception e)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an issue with dotCover 2016.3 and the new style "portable" pdb files.

You can either:

- use "full" pdb files, by editing the property in project.json
- uncheck the "Include not loaded solution assemblies into coverage results" setting in ReSharper → Options → dotCover → General.

This will be fixed in 2017.1